# Should a site map reference itself?

Tags: language-agnostic

Bit of a philosophical question.

If you have a public website with a site map. Should the site map reference itself?

I can't think of any reason it should but was thinking in terms of accessibility etc or something I had overlooked.

Comment: So anyone interested can use the sitemap to find the sitemap of the site ? that seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Er no, that's just silly.

Comment: I don't think it's silly, it's like "table of contents" referring to itself which is quite common (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The site map is a part of the site itself, as well as the summary of the site's layout; so yes I, personally, include a reference *to* the site map *in* the site map. I'm aware that there are some that feel a web-page should not link to itself, though I think that's more relevant -to avoid confusing users- in a breadcrumb trail than here.

It's an interesting question; I'm curious to see what others think.

Comment: It is quite normal for a home page to have a link to the home page itself (like the Stack Overflow logo on Stack Overflow). Having a SiteMap link to itself is just pointless.

Comment: But as you say- it is interesting to see what others think.

Answer (score 0):

sure, why not, actually, if it is, then one can use it to refer to the site map in the future (that is, to know where to find the site map next time fetching the site).

Comment: In that case, what is wrong with a 301 redirect if you decided to move the SiteMap?